# How to add hyperlinks in text in SVG with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I thought that my code here would work when a user sends a message that includes a `http://`, but it doesn't:

```
function showMessage(nameStr, contentStr, textColor) {

    var node = document.getElementById("chatbox");
    var nameNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan", textColor);

    nameNode.setAttribute("x", 100);
    nameNode.setAttribute("dy", 20);
    nameNode.setAttribute("fill", textColor);
    nameNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameStr));

    node.appendChild(nameNode);

    var contentNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");

    contentStr = contentStr.replace(/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?)/g,
        '<a target="blank" href="$1">$1</a>');

    contentNode.setAttribute("x", 200);
    contentNode.setAttribute("fill", textColor);
    contentNode.innerHTML = contentStr;

    // Add the name to the text node
    node.appendChild(contentNode);
}
```

Can anyone find an error within this code?

- `nameStr` is the name of the person sending the message,
- `contentStr` is what the user input, and which the program should automatically change so any hyperlinks become clickable links, and
- `textColor` is just the color of the message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is a bit too complex for the question you're asking. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Perhaps only one line is relevant. Have you tested it in isolation?

Comment: That regex makes a lot of faulty assumptions about URLs.

Comment: I think the code works fine when I checked the replacing script :/

Comment: Exactly which part does not work? The text does not appear? The color is wrong? The hyperlinks don't work?

Comment: The code in this question seems remarkably similar to the code [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408663/hyperlink-in-tspan-svg-not-shown). Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

To make hyperlinks work inside an `svg` element, you should set up the XLink namespace, in addition to the default one for `svg`:

```
<svg width="500" height="500" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
```

Then you can use the `xlink:href` attribute:

```
<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com">click here</a>
```

Taking it all together in this snippet:

```js
function showMessage(nameStr, contentStr, textColor) {

    var node = document.getElementById("chatbox");
    var nameNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan", textColor);

    nameNode.setAttribute("x", 100);
    nameNode.setAttribute("dy", 20);
    nameNode.setAttribute("fill", textColor);
    nameNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameStr));

    node.appendChild(nameNode);

    var contentNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");

    contentStr = contentStr.replace(/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?)/g,
        '<a fill="purple" target="blank" xlink:href="$1">$1</a>'); // "xlink:" added!

    contentNode.setAttribute("x", 200);
    contentNode.setAttribute("fill", textColor);
    contentNode.innerHTML = contentStr;

    // Add the name to the text node
    node.appendChild(contentNode);
}
// Sample call:
showMessage('John Doe', 'click this http://www.example.com', 'blue');
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     version="1.1">

<text id="chatbox"></text>

</svg>
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! Now that it works, how would I be able to change the color of the hyperlink and underline it as well? Can't believe I missed having the right code by that much haha

Comment: For color, add the color attribute to `<a>`. For underline, it is easier to use a CSS definition for all `<a>`. I have added both in my answer just now.